# SuperCSV append rather than overwrite?

Tags: java, android, csv, supercsv

Is it possible to add new lines to a CSV file, rather than overwrite the last one?

Here is my method I call when I want to add a new line:

```
private static void writeWithCsvMapWriter() throws Exception 
{
    final String[] header = new String[] { "Engineer", "Time/Date", "Project", "Test ID", "Data Centre", "Data Hall", "Row", "Grille", "I/S" };

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    final Map<String, Object> NewRow = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    NewRow.put(header[0], Name.getText().toString());
    NewRow.put(header[1], currentDateandTime);
    NewRow.put(header[2], "Expect");
    NewRow.put(header[3], TestID.getText());
    NewRow.put(header[4], DataCentre.getText());
    NewRow.put(header[5], DataHall.getText());
    NewRow.put(header[6], Row.getText());
    NewRow.put(header[7], Grille.getText());
    NewRow.put(header[8], IS.getText());

    ICsvMapWriter mapWriter = null;

    try 
    {
        mapWriter = new CsvMapWriter(new FileWriter("data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME +"/writeWithCsvMapWriter.csv"), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

        mapWriter.writeHeader(header);
        mapWriter.write(NewRow, header, processors);  
    }
    finally 
    {
        if( mapWriter != null ) 
        {
            mapWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `true` to the parameters in `new FileWriter`:

```
mapWriter = new CsvMapWriter(new FileWriter(".../writeWithCsvMapWriter.csv", true), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
```

Comment: Perfect, I should of tried this, I'm sure this is how you do it in .NET.

Comment: Do note that every time you run this, it will also cause the possible header line to be outputted and appended to the file again

Answer (score 1):

As frickskit pointed out: the trick is to add `true` as the second parameter of `new FileWriter()`, but this will add the header underneath existing rows again as well. Use something in the lines of the following to check for the existence of a header in an existing file first before you decide to write it out.

```java
public void write(String fileName, List<Map<String, String>> lines) throws IOException {
    final String[] HEADER = new String[] {
        "Column1",
        "Column2",
        "Column3"
    };

    boolean writeHeader = true;

    try (ICsvMapReader mapReader = new CsvMapReader(new FileReader(fileName), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE)) {

        final String[] existingHeader = mapReader.getHeader(true);

        if (Arrays.equals(existingHeader, HEADER)) {
            writeHeader = false;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}

    try (ICsvMapWriter mapWriter = new CsvMapWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE)) {

        final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

        if (writeHeader) {
            mapWriter.writeHeader(HEADER);
        }

        for (Map<String, String> entry : lines) {
            mapWriter.write(entry, HEADER, processors);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you write a lot of csv-records, this can be resource-consuming. reading every time before writing, but one can write a separate method only for writing the header at the beginning