# How to append data to File using SuperCSV using CsvListWriter

Tags: java, file, csv, supercsv

I have a method to write data to a file.

```
public void writeCSFFileData(List<String> fileData){
    try {
        CsvListWriter csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(new FileWriter("/path/file.csv"), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
        csvWriter.write(fileData);
        csvWriter.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        SimpleLogger.getInstance().writeError(e);
    }
```

The above method is called several times to write to a file.
But, each time the file is not appended instead it is overwritten.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SuperCSV append rather than overwrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729977/supercsv-append-rather-than-overwrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, I just need to add `true` in FileWriter to append the data.

Ex: `new FileWriter("/path/file.csv",true)`